# Dynamically loading terms in a term reference tree from a huge taxonomy so users may select nodes as options

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, performance

I'm trying to create a form that uses a bushy taxonomy of about 30,000 (max depth is ~9) terms to allow users to select multiple nodes from the tree.  [The Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) fits the functionality I need perfectly, but with the size tree that I'm using each expand/collapse or select event takes a couple of seconds to complete, which isn't acceptable in terms of performance.

I'm new to drupal, but haven't been able to find a widget that can perform this task quickly. Are there any D7 widgets or modules that can accomplish this task? It seems that if I were able to have the widget not load all of the children all at once that performance might increase, but I can't say I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some contrib modules:
[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

> Module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy. [Demo](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy)

[Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs)

> Defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by
>   "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.

You can use it with [High-performance JavaScript callback handler](https://www.drupal.org/project/js)

Also you can try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_jstree